# django.contrib.auth import views || Autenticação de Login e redirecionamento de url

Tags: python, django, login, auth, pycharm

Estou tentando usar as bibliotecas do Django para verificar se o usuario está logado, e, só então, ele poder entrar nas paginas do meu website.
Estou codificando de acordo com algumas aulas da internet, no exemplo dele foi funcional, e ele mostrou um erro, pedindo `register/login.html`, em seguida ele criou diretório `template/register/login.html` assim para verificar se o usuário está logado, e se não, abrir uma tela de login.

Agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda, indicação, ou melhora no meu código.

Pasta principal do projeto, **urls.py**.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from clientes import urls as clientes_urls
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('clientes/', include(clientes_urls)),
    path('login/', auth_views.auth_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.auth_logout, name='logout'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**#Templates**

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Tela do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit 1: Não tem nenhuma `def`, no **views.py**, chamando qualquer diretorio ''login''(seja por html, função ou biblioteca do django), tanto no meu código quanto no código que estou me baseando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
```

Meu problema era com a versão do django, ao utilizar o código dessa forma ele funciona da forma que eu desejava.

Answer (score -2):

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
# Pagina de login
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
name='login'),

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).